# Evaluating $I(x)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{du}{x^2\cos^2u+\sin^2u}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, alternative-proof

The following is from a  national junior contest of an african country.

> Find the integral $$I(x)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{du}{x^2\cos^2u+\sin^2u}}$$

$$\underline{\textbf{My attempt:}}$$

Rewrite the integral as $$I(x)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{1+\tan^2u}{x^2+\tan^2u}}du$$ then do the substitution $\tan u=\lambda x$, this gives:
$$I(x)=\int_{0}^{\alpha}{\frac{1+\lambda^2x^2}{x^2+\lambda^2x^2}\times\frac{xd\lambda}{1+\lambda^2x^2}}=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{\alpha}{\frac{d\lambda}{1+\lambda^2}}.$$
The problem is the value of $\alpha$, it seems that:

> If $x>0$ we have to choose $\alpha=\infty$, if not $\alpha=-\infty$. This yields:
>
> If $x>0\quad I(x)=\frac{\pi}{2x}$
>
> If $x<0\quad I(x)=-\frac{\pi}{2x}$
>
> Thus $I(x)=\frac{\pi}{2|x|}$ if $x\ne 0$
> Is this correct? Any alternative proof?

$\textbf{Addendum}$: I tried solve it
using Feynman Trick without issue. I’m pretty lsure that one can do it with that trick. Waiting to see someone solve with Feynman. Merci!!!

Comment: I need some sleep right now, but it seems to me that $I(-x)=I(x)$ thus all you get is one case. $I(x)=\frac{\pi}{2x}$.

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem. Maybe this is more clear:$$I(x)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{du}{x^2 \cos^2 u+\sin^2 u}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sec^2 u}{x^2+\tan^2 u}du\overset{\tan u =y}=\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\pi}{2 x}$$
Where of course $x\neq 0$, and $I(x)=I(-x)$.

Comment: It's fine to use $\tan(\pi/2)=\infty$, instead of $-\infty$

Comment: I’m not familiar with sec and cosec. These functions are most of time being avoided in French math program.

Comment: Well, just replace $\sec u$ with$\frac{1}{\cos u}$. And of course we have $(\tan u)'=\frac{1}{\cos^2 u}$. 
$$I(x)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{du}{x^2 \cos^2 u+\sin^2 u}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(tan u)'}{x^2+\tan^2 u}du\overset{\tan u =y}=\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\pi}{2 x}$$

Comment: Ok this more clear to me now

Comment: In fact we can suppose wlog $x>0$ since $I(x)$ is an even function then solve it for $x>0$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}I(x)&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{du}{x^2\cos^2u+\sin^2u}}\,du\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{du}{x^2+\tan^2u}}\times \dfrac{1}{\cos^2 u}\,du\\
\end{align}

The function is not defined for $x=0$.

Observe that, $I(-x)=I(x)$

Perform the change of variable $y=\tan u$,and $x>0$
\begin{align}I(x)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{du}{x^2+u^2}}\,\\
&=\left[\dfrac{1}{x}\arctan\left(\dfrac{u}{x}\right)\right]_0^{\infty}\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2x}
\end{align}
Therefore,
For $x\neq 0$,
$\boxed{I(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2\left|x\right|}}$

Comment: Thanks you for your answer